# Redis replication chain of slaves(replicas) when intermediate replica crashes

Tags: redis, replication

I have this situation. A Redis Master, with a replica(Slave) R1, for redundancy, which can be promoted to Master in case of failure, plus two extra replicas, R2 and R3, which are only for replication, and can't be promoted.

The point is, R2 and R3 are over a WAN, so in other to save bandwidth, I was thinking about making R3 a "replicaof" R2. I know it works, but my problem is :

if R2 crashes, what happens to R3? How can it be then connected to the Master instead? I mean automatically, like using Redis-sentinels, for instance. And, if that is possible, what will happen when R2 recovers?

Ay ideas?

Best Regards,

Luis

Answer (score 0):

> if R2 crashes, what happens to R3?

R3 disconnects from R2, and CANNOT sync with the master. Although R3 is still in slave role.

> How can it be then connected to the Master instead?

AFAIK, you have to manually reconfig R3 to be a slave of the master.

However, this is an interesting scenario, I think you can open an issue to Redis developers.